# Eager-loading content and merging queries

Tags: craft3, eager-loading, queries, plugin-neo

sorry if the following question is too basic, but I've spent quite some time digging now so I decided to reach out for help.

### Is 250 DB queries too many?

I have a Neo field "modules" that can contain different ~30 other fields for content, such as "Headline", "WYSISG Block", "Buttons", etc. I think this is a common pattern for CraftCMS. The modules are then rendered as follows:

```
{% for module in entry.modules %} 
    {% include alias('@organisms/o-' ~ module.type.handle|replace('/(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '-$0')|lower) ignore missing with module %}
{% endfor %}
```

With 14 content blocks this results in **~250 DB queries -- is this too many**?

### Reducing the number of queries

I tried to bring the number of queries down by **eager-loading**, adding the following:

```
{% set eagerLoadedModules = entry.modules.with(
    [
        'modules.headlineWithContent:backgroundImage',
        'modules.headlineWithContent:backgroundImageMobile',
        'modules.headlineWithContent:backgroundPosition',
        'modules.headlineWithContent:fieldTitle',
        'modules.headlineWithContent:text',
        '...', 
    ]
).all() %} 


{% for module in eagerLoadedModules %} 
    {% include alias('@organisms/o-' ~ module.type.handle|replace('/(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '-$0')|lower) ignore missing with module  %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this did not reduce the number of queries compared to the "dummy" version. I thought the problem was that eager-loading is rather meant for "N+1 queries" situations which is not really my use-case. I hoped that CraftCMS would **merge the eager-load into one big query**, but it seems to not be the case.

Can you please provide me with code examples and pointers on how to bring the number of queries down in this case?

- Craft: 3.9.6
- Neo: 2.13.19

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I've never used Neo before, but I'll answer as if it were a standard Craft matrix field, as I'd expect/hope that it would work the same way(?!):

1. First, correct your syntax: In `entry.modules.with...` you're already in the context of your field called `modules`, so you shouldn't repeat the `modules. ...` part at the start of each eager loadable thing.
2. Second, there is no value in eager loading things that are not relationships pointing to other elements, ie: assets, categories, entries, users, or tags. So don't attempt to eager load text fields and lightswitches - it's meaningless.
3. For assets, don't forget to also eager load any transforms that you might be using.

Syntax might then look like this:

```twig
{% set eagerLoadedModules = entry.modules.with([
    ['headlineWithContent:backgroundImage', {withTransforms: arrayOfTransforms1}],
    ['headlineWithContent:backgroundImageMobile', {withTransforms: arrayOfTransforms2}]
]).all() %}
```

Depending on how you set your transforms (control panel vs templates vs something custom like in config/custom.php) your transform arrays might look something like this:

```twig
{% set arrayOfTransforms1 = [
    {width: 1980},
    {width: 1700},
    {width: 1200},
    {width: 800},
    {width: 1980, format: 'webp'},
    {width: 1700, format: 'webp'},
    {width: 1200, format: 'webp'},
    {width: 800, format: 'webp'},
] %}

{% set arrayOfTransforms2 = [
    {width: 900, height: 900, mode: 'crop'},
    {width: 500, height: 500, mode: 'crop'},
] %}
```

(Aside: to avoid manual duplication of the webp variants, and also to make my transforms available globally without bumping into awkward Twig parse order issues, I put mine in config/custom.php like this: https://github.com/cld-agency/craftwind-boilerplate/blob/craft-4/config/custom.php)